# Get source HTML from encoded EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm displaying formatted text in an EditText as such:

```
String msg = <b>Some text here</b>;
EditText txtMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
txtMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

That displays in the EditText as "**Some text here.**" Then, later, I'd like to pull the text from that EditText complete with the tags. However, when I use:

```
txtMsg.getText().toString();
```

It just gives me "Some text here" with no formatting.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try as to get Text with HTML formatting back from EditText:

```
String msgtext=Html.toHtml(txtMsg.getText());
```

Comment: This works, although it includes some tags I don't want. For example, <b>Hello</b> in the textbox returns as <p dir=ltr><b>Hello</b></p>, but with regular expressions I'm able to strip excess tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Html.toHtml is deprecated in Java and Android N

You better use

```
HtmlCompat.toHtml(
                        txtMsg.text,
                        HtmlCompat.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL
                    )
```

for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat.html?